# How do I correctly structure & associate a delegated type and its associations within Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, polymorphic-associations, delegation

In an effort to not have multiple of the same record/similar records I'm investigating using `delegated_type` however Im stumped on just how my associations should/would work.

I've a table, `Item` that uses delegation for class table inheritance for `InvoiceItem`, `OrderItem`, `NoteItem` and `BasketItem`.

I have parent tables for `item`, `PurchaseOrder`, `DeliveryNote` and `Invoice`.

- A `PurchaseOrder` will have many items, where the `itemable` is `OrderItem` OR `BasketItem`.
- A `DeliveryNote` will have many items, where the `itemable` is `NoteItem`
- An `Invoice` will have many items, where the `itemable` is `InvoiceItem`

`item.rb`

```
delegated_type :itemable, primary_key: :uuid, types: ["OrderItem", "InvoiceItem", "NoteItem", "BasketItem"]
```

`NoteItem/InvoiceItem/OrderItem/BasketItem`

```
has_one :item, as: :itemable, dependent: :destroy
```

Now I'm unsure if an `Item` should belong to a `PurchaseOrder` or whether the inherited table (`OrderItem/BasketItem`) should be the relation.

An example:

`PurchaseOrder.rb`

```
has_many :order_items, -> { where(itemable_type: OrderItem) }, class_name: "Items",
                                                                            foreign_key: "purchase_order_id",
                                                                            inverse_of: :purchase_order,
                                                                            dependent: :destroy
```

`OrderItem.rb`

```
belongs_to :purchase_order, class_name: "PurchaseOrder"
```

I believe the first option should be the correct way, but I'm unsure how that `belongs_to` would work for the sub-items, should an `OrderItem` `belong_to` a `PurchaseOrder`? This would result in a `PurchaseOrder` having many items where `itemable` is `OrderItem`, but only the `OrderItem` belongs to the `PurchaseOrder`, but perhaps this is correct and I am misinterpreting the `delegated_type` documentation.

Thanks.

Documentation:

- https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/DelegatedType.html

Versions:
Rails `7.0.4`, Ruby `3.0.1` and PGSQL `14`

Comment: I would really take a pause here and consider if you're going a bit too far in your quest to eliminate duplication and if the additional complexity you're introducing isn't actually a lot worse. Sure you'll have three different tables with largely the same columns but that also mean the total size of the tables will be smaller. I also belive that as you build your app you'll discover that the entities will start to diverge.

Comment: Also you should consider that delegated types use polymorphic associations which means you will not have any real foreign key constraints to guarentee the referential integrity of all this data (and it look like pretty import data).

Comment: Thanks both - I am still just investigating this avenue and I appreciate your thoughts on it. Perhaps delegation is better for smaller, less consequential cases.

Comment: Delegated types and polymorphism are useful when you want to make something like ActiveStorage where you can plug the functionality into any given class. But it's not how you should structure the core buisness logic in your application.

Comment: I would instead just lay the tables out in the most simple way possible (one designated table for each type) and then use [WET](https://betterprogramming.pub/when-dry-doesnt-work-go-wet-6befda0444bf) to decide when to extract the shared functionality into modules or when to use inheritance. Not that this doesn't apply to the database side as databases are tabular and relational. Inheritance and mixins don't actually exist in the SQL world.